# MkMapView Crash iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mapkit, snapkit

I am using SnapKit and programmatically adding a MkMapview. Every time i background the application it is crashing with this exception -
`std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument`

I am aware of having to deallocate your delegate, but at this point I haven't even set the delegate and it still crashing.

I'm sure it is the map because if I comment out the part where I am adding my map to the view, there is no crash. I have also commented out any code with the map so it is simply displaying a map and crashing on the background. I don't think there's any relevant code to add but this

```
self.view.addSubview(self.map)
```

where self is an UIView and map is MkMapView.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am also getting a mutex lock error when I background my app.  I added the MKMapView using the storyboard.  Adding location permissions didn't help.  The app only crashes when attached to the debugger.  Running on a stand-alone device does not crash when I background the app.

Comment: have you solved this?? I have the same error when my mapkit view controller when to the background...

Answer (score 2):

Even though it was posted 9 months ago, I found the solution (workaround..) to this problem. I was having crashes with my app when entering background with a mapview and attached to a debugger.

It seems that the mapkit uses some Metal API and there might be some problems underneath. You have to disable runtime Metal API checking and it won't crash.

Go to your target settings and under the 'Diagnostics' tab, uncheck the 'API Validation' on the Metal section.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you've requested location permissions with Core Location. I had this crash before authentication, then i granted permission and it no longer crashed. Weird and definitely a bug as of iOS 14 but...